# Openlayers WKT returning too big gps coordinates

Tags: javascript, sql, gps, openlayers

I'm using Openlayers 2.13 to draw polygons.
I need to save the polygons in my database.
I use the following code to retrieve a WKT (Well-know Text) format of the polygon:
    getGeometry().toString();

The WKT looks like this:

```
"POLYGON((2214109.1963538 -3576110.9131445,2150513.5888293 -3766897.7357178,2529641.249071 -3656828.4150024,2529641.249071 -3656828.4150024,2214109.1963538 -3576110.9131445))"
```

However, when I try to write that to the DB i get the following error:

```
24201: Latitude values must be between -90 and 90 degrees.
```

Why are the GPS coordinates from Openlayers so big?

I've tried changing the projection of the map, but to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to insert into a latlon geometry column (as defined in your database) a geometry in another projection system.

You should reproject the geometry before transforming it to WKT.
You need something like this:

```
var srcPrj = new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:3857'): //put your map projection here!
var trgPrj = new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:4326');
var geometry = feature.getGeometry();
geometry = geometry.transform(srcPrj, trgPrj);
var wkt = geometry.toString();
```

Comment: Thank you, I was trying to change the projection of the system, instead of transforming the WKT before storing it in my database.